# Android apk rejected

Tags: java, android, google-play

I want to update one of my apps switching from cordova to native Android code but I got this message in the Developer Console after submitting my new apk

> Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Device and
>   Network Abuse policy. Before submitting your app for another review,
>   read through the policy and modify your app to make sure it doesn't
>   enable background play of YouTube videos. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

The thing is I don't use any Youtube thing in my app. I just send a `GET` request to a webserver api which returns me back a url which then I pass to `ChromeCustomTabs`

This is the code that makes the query(An `AsyncTask`) and broadcasts the result back to my activity

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    String newUrl = doc.text();

    Intent response = new Intent(Home.INTENT_FILTER_SERVICE_READY);
    response.putExtra(Home.INTENT_EXTRA_NAME, newUrl);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Application.getContext()).sendBroadcast(response);
```

And then this is how I get the link back in my activity and open the url in `ChromeCustomTabs` if available or in the default browser.

```
String newUrl = intent.getExtras().getString(INTENT_EXTRA_NAME);

if(Functions.isChromeCustomTabsSupported()) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.setToolbarColor(Color.parseColor("#36465D"));
    builder.setStartAnimations(Home.this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    builder.setExitAnimations(Home.this, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    builder.addDefaultShareMenuItem();

    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(Home.this, Uri.parse(newUrl));
} else {
    Intent openInBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openInBrowser.setData(Uri.parse(newUrl));
    startActivity(openInBrowser);
}
```